# Adding Models to MLFlow Registry from Java

Tags: java, mlflow

I am trying to add models from my java code to the "Registered Models" tab in MLflow.

Every code I find is in python and uses stuff like:

```
mlflow.sklearn.log_model(
        sk_model=model,
        artifact_path="sklearn-model",
        signature=signature,
        registered_model_name="sk-learn-random-forest-reg-model",
)
```

or alternatively

```
client = MlflowClient()
client.create_registered_model(name)
```

When creating a client in java like this

```
MlflowClient client = new MlflowClient(URI)
```

I can easily interact with Experiments. I can log performances and create Runs. Great! But how do I put something into the ModelRegistry from Java? I cannot find any function which is close to log_model or create_registered?
I see functions to get the last version and so on, but that's it?

Thanks!
Martin

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn’t a feature that’s been implemented.

I have taken a look through the Java mlflow client class and no such method exists.

What’s more, much of the core functionality stems from a wrapper class which wraps the mlflow command line client, which in turn depends on python packages.

See:

[1] https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/java/client/src/main/java/org/mlflow/tracking/MlflowClient.java

[2] https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/java/client/src/main/java/org/mlflow/artifacts/CliBasedArtifactRepository.java